# Read txt file backwards

Tags: c#

u currently have this code that reads a txt file. I would like to make it read the file backward.
it currently displays "Backwards run sentences until boggles the mind"
I would like to make it display "mind the boggles until sentences run Backwards"

```
        // Read sentences ...
        while (!infile.EndOfStream)
        {
            // Read a line from the file, as a whole string
            string line = infile.ReadLine();
            // Split string into 'words', separated by spaces
            string[] words = line.Split(' ');

            // Loop through each 'word' found
            for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
            {
                // Output current word
                Console.Write(words[i]);
                // Output a space between every word, except for the last one
                if (i <= words.Length + 1)
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
            }
            // Output a newline chatracter at the end of the sentence
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        infile.Close(); // Be a tidy kiwi

        // Wait for user to have read the output
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("<Press enter to finish>");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

After you get your original array of words - you can simply reverse it:

```
 string[] words = line.Split(' ');
 Array.Reverse(words, 0, words.Length);
```

For more see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.reverse?view=net-5.0